# Difference between FORWARD and FORWARD_direct chain in filter table?

Tags: linux, iptables, nat, firewalld

I needed to give ssh access to one of my virtual machines from internet.

I added a NAT rule to my firewalld table but it does not work.

```
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule 'rule family="ipv4" destination address=$mypublicip forward-port port="4444" protocol="tcp" to-port="22" to-addr="$myprivateip"'
```

After more investigation I figured out that I can add combination of the following two rules using iptables and it worked fine.

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 4444 -j DNAT --to $myprivateip:22
iptables -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -d $myprivateip -j ACCEPT
```

As I like firewall-cmd command line I tried to add the same iptables rule using firewall-cmd command line and I did it using the following comands.

```
firewall-cmd --direct --permanent --add-rule ipv4 nat PREROUTING 0 -d $myip -p tcp --dport 4444 -j DNAT --to $myprivateip:22
firewall-cmd --direct --permanent --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -o virbr0 -d $myprivateip -j ACCEPT
```

After checking my firewall tables I realized that the last 2 rules exist in PREROUTING_direct and FORWARD_direct tables and they did not work properly and my SSH access is not provided.

What is the difference between PREROUTING & PREROUTING_direct or FORWARD & FORWARD_direct tables? And if they are the same tables just for --direct rules why they don't work like PREROUTING & FORWARD tables?